# Formatting Wrong on IE 11 and Edge

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, formatting, display

I am working on a website that someone else started from a template so not everything in it is mine. I am not a web designer by trade, but I do have coding experience. Everything displays perfectly in Firefox and chrome, and near perfectly in Edge, but quite wrong in IE11.

Examples: https://i.stack.imgur.com/15BMM.jpg

Firefox:

[image]

Edge:

[image]

Internet Explorer 11:

[image]

I cant seem to figure out why the background color isn't displaying of certain aspects when viewed with internet explorer. I also can't seem to figure out why the text isn't floating right so it sits next to the picture. The header and footer also display incorrectly when viewed in IE 11.

Here is the HTML involving the text that is supposed to be next to the picture:

```
<aside> 
<h3> Fliteway Technologies</h3>
<p>Your Single Source for Soil and Groundwater Remediation Equipment</p>
<h3><a href="Fliteway Tour.pdf">Take a Tour!</a></h3>
</aside>
```

and here is the CSS:

```
aside {
float: right;
width: 225px;
height: auto;
background-color: #E3E3E3 !important;
background-color: rgba(227, 227, 227, 1);
background:#E3E3E3;
margin-top: 0;
clear: left;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: 0;
margin-bottom: auto;
display: block;
visibility: inherit;
```

There is a bit of clutter in the CSS as I have been trying anything I come across online to try to fix the problem. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated as I am really stuck on this.

picture HTML:

```
<sidepicture>
<div class="sidepicture"><img src="_images/Bld with Addition.jpg" alt="Shop" width="564" height="270"></div>
</sidepicture>
```

picture CSS:

```
.sidepicture {
display:inherit;
}
```

Comment: We need the html/css for the picture as well as its parent element, though you should avoid using float for layout, ... and which browsers do you need to support? ... from IE11 and up?

Comment: Ok, I have added the HTML and CSS for the picture. I am not quite sure what you mean by parent element though, I am pretty new to this still. How would you recommend I do formatting then?

Comment: What @LGSon is asking is css for `aside` element. Without that the only tip i can give you is use ms style variables ie when you write `display:block` below that also write `display:-ms-block`.

Comment: I added a parent element in my answer, the `wrapper`, where a parent element means the element that have, int this case, the `aside` and `sidepicture` as its children.

Comment: I think you should wrap both  in a container div and vertical align top. Or use bootstrap and do a md-6-6 grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For newer browsers I recommend using `flex`

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
aside {
  width: 225px;
  background:#E3E3E3;
}  

sidepicture {
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <sidepicture>
    <div class="sidepicture">
      <img src="_images/Bld with Addition.jpg" alt="Shop" width="564" height="270"></div>
  </sidepicture>
  <aside> 
    <h3> Fliteway Technologies</h3>
    <p>Your Single Source for Soil and Groundwater Remediation Equipment</p>
    <h3><a href="Fliteway Tour.pdf">Take a Tour!</a></h3>
  </aside>
</div>
```

For older browsers I would use `display: table`

*Side note: If to target older browsers be aware they might not support custom tags like your `<sidepicture>`*

```css
.wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
aside {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 225px;
  background:#E3E3E3;
  vertical-align: top;
}  

sidepicture {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <sidepicture>
    <div class="sidepicture">
      <img src="_images/Bld with Addition.jpg" alt="Shop" width="564" height="270"></div>
  </sidepicture>
  <aside> 
    <h3> Fliteway Technologies</h3>
    <p>Your Single Source for Soil and Groundwater Remediation Equipment</p>
    <h3><a href="Fliteway Tour.pdf">Take a Tour!</a></h3>
  </aside>
</div>
```

Comment: This fixed the display problems in Edge, and I am very appreciative of that, however there was no visible change when viewed in IE 11.

Comment: @Echo1 I tested the `flex` version using the above snippet in Chrome, Firefox, Edge, IE11 and they all render the same result. If you own code does not, I'll need to see it.

Comment: Here is the HTML and CSS files. If you need anything else, I would be happing to help. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/yel9due2qis1v3k/AABNO-XTAgLjueL6nkbPQyGRa?dl=0

Comment: @Echo1 Tested your code and it work for me in IE11. Make sure that IE specific style sheet doesn't load and have some other rules overriding the one I gave you. If you can give me a link to the page running on your web server would be better

Comment: Currently the site isn't on the web server, I am just previewing the webpages in browser via dreamweaver. The IE only stylesheet is the exact same at the moment but with the text at a different color to see if it changed anything(it didn't) so would i be better off just removing the IE only stylesheet?

Comment: @Echo1 When you run IE like that, locally, it most likely runs in compatibility mode, and if, that's the reason it doesn't render properly, so when you run it from a web server it will work. Regarding IE style sheet, I can't say whether you can remove it or not, I saw you have a shim running too and that one might need it so you need to do some trial and error and see what stops work when removed

Comment: Compatibility mode was the problem. Thank you so much.